# Intuition behind why solution to optimization problem occurs at saddle point of Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm studying the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), and the Wikipedia page says

> The solution corresponding to the original constrained optimization is always a saddle point of the Lagrangian function.

Why intuitively is this the case? I have been looking at [these](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eggordon/lp.pdf) notes which also state this result and give an example, but don't explain why this is the case in general.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try calculating the Hessian and applying the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test. It's probably easiest to try for functions of one variable first (so that the Langrangian function takes two arguments).

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I know how to find saddle points. I am asking why minimums and maximums occur at saddle points specifically.

Comment: Okay... but have you considered what the saddle points of your Lagrangian function look like?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou From the examples I have looked at, for a minimization problem, the Lagrangian is typically increasing in the directions of the variables on either side of a saddle point and decreasing or staying constant in the directions of the multipliers. For example, this is true of the problem: minimize (or maximize) $x^2$ subject to $x=1$. Then the Lagrangian is $L(x, \lambda) = x^2 + \lambda(x - 1)$. There is a saddle point at $(x=1, \lambda = -2)$, which obeys the observations cited above. But I'm not sure if this is always the case, and if so, why?